# PhoneGap 1.3.0 iPad content rotation incorrect

Tags: cordova

I've got the code for an old PhoneGap 1.3.0 app running on iPad, but the screen rotation is off. The app plist is set to support landscape only (which the app starts in), but then the content gets rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise once the splash screen has been displayed.

The status bar appears at the top of the screen, so it's the actual web view content that is rotated, not the view controller.

Does any body have any ideas where to start looking for a possible fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further Googling returns this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/KJmvRIajsm8

The following line in PhoneGapDelegate.m

```
[self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
```

should be changed to

```
[self.window setRootViewController:self.viewController];
```

Alternatively, I could have used a newer version of PhoneGap, but I really didn't have time to mess about updating the project.

Comment: I have the same issue, but this solution didn't work for me :(

Comment: Hi Abu, I may be able to help you. It's the WebView that needs to have it's rootViewController set. If you open the AppDelegate.m and find: 

    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView

and add the following to it: 

  [theWebView.window setRootViewController:self.viewController];